# Using a XAML font family breaks some Unicode glyphs

Tags: c#, xaml, unicode, fonts

I am trying to display various Unicode characters in a XAML `TextBlock` without any particular attributes:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}" Foreground="Black" />
```

This works well for all scripts on my Windows 8.1 system, except for emoji characters:

[image: Latin OK]
[image: Emoji Broken]
[image: Cyrillic OK]

Since these symbols are available in the **Segoe UI Symbol** font, I simply added it to `FontFamily`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}" Foreground="Black"
           FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" />
```

However, now some Cyrillic symbols are broken:

[image: Latin OK]
[image: Emoji OK]
[image: Cyrillic Broken]

So I tried to enable several fonts, including [composite fonts listed on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.aspx):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}" Foreground="Black"
           FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, Segoe UI Symbol,
                       Open Sans, Arial, Microsoft Sans Serif, Tahoma,
                       Courier New, Times New Roman, Global User Interface,
                       Portable User Interface" />
```

But I get exactly the same result:

[image: Latin OK]
[image: Emoji OK]
[image: Cyrillic Broken]

How can I fix this? Isn’t **Global User Interface** supposed to give me a decent fallback for all characters? What could my `TextBlock` be using when I specify no `FontFamily`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it. It appears that:

- `Segoe UI` is needed **in addition** to `Segoe UI Symbol`.
- `Segoe UI Symbol` will mess up some characters and fonts that follow it will not be used; it should therefore be **moved to the end**.

The following string worked and all my glyphs now get rendered:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}" Foreground="Black"
           FontFamily="Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande,
                       Open Sans, Arial, Microsoft Sans Serif, Tahoma,
                       Courier New, Times New Roman, Global User Interface,
                       Portable User Interface, Segoe UI Symbol" />
```